# Break JSON response into new line without removing comma React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I receive a JSON response I want this to be broken into a new line.

> This solution breaks into a new line but it also removes the `","` after every line

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(op.responses['properties'][key]).split(",").join("\n")}</div>
```

I everything to break into a new line without removing the "comma `,` ".

Comment: JSON is a data transport format, why use JSON.stringify and then editing the resulting string instead of just directly generating the string you need from `op.responses.properties[key]`? What possible benefit could JSON give here?

Comment: To what end are you inserting these new-lines? So they look nice when you inspect dom elements in the debugger? New lines in a `<div>` won't show in the rendered HTML. You'd need paragraphs, or `<br>` tags for that to happen. Why not go for proper, indented formatting with `JSON.stringify(something, null, 2)`, then dump it in a `<pre>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple: do it exactly like you are doing it, but add a comma to your 'join'

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(op.responses['properties'][key]).split(",").join(",\n")}</div>
```